# Obtener datos entre 2 fechas laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Mediante los 2 inputdate quiero obtener todos los registros comprendidos entre ellos 2. Tengo la consulta construida pero cuando le doy al boton buscar no ocurre nada solo me muestra los 2 datos en la barra de firefox, Agradeceria su ayuda

**Mi controlador**

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\ClienteModel;


class ReporteController extends Controller
{

private function convertDate($date)
{
    if ($date === null) {
        return null;
    }

    $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    if ($dt) {
        return $dt->format('Y-m-d');
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}


public function filtrar(Request $request){
  if ($request){


        $query=trim($request->get('searchText'));

  $fec_email = $this->convertDate($request->Input('fec_email'));
  $fec_fin_instalacion = $this->convertDate($request->Input('fec_fin_instalacion'));

         $Reportes= DB::table('cliente')
         ->whereBetween('fec_ini_instalacion',[$fec_email,$fec_fin_instalacion])
         ->get();
       // return view('Vistas.Reportes.index', compact('Reportes'));
       return view('Vistas.Reportes.index',["Reportes"=>$Reportes,"searchText"=>$query]);


         }

}

}
```

**Vista search**

```html
<!---Recordar que dicha ruta llamara a nuestro metodo index  y realizara el filtro por medio del searchtext-->

{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'Vistas/Reportes','method'=>'GET','autocomplete'=>'off','role'=>'search'))!!}

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="">Fecha email</label>
  <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="fec_email"  value="fec_email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="">Fin de la instalacion </label>
  <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="fec_fin_instalacion" value="fec_fin_instalacion">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ $searchText }}">Buscar</button>

    </span>
</div>

</div>




{{Form::close()}}
```

**index**

```html
@extends('template.admin')


@section('contenido')

<h1>Reportes</h1>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      @include('Vistas.Reportes.search')
 </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">

               <thead>
                <th>Fecha</th>
               </thead>
               @foreach($Reportes as $repo)

               <tr>
                 <td>{{ $repo->fec_ini_instalacion }}</td>

               </tr>

                @endforeach

   </table>

  </div>

 </div>

</div>

@endsection
```

[image: Añado una imagen del frontend]

Answer (score 1):

yo de sql no se practicamente nada, pero hice unos marcadores de los cuales el icono dependia de la diferencia de la fecha actual con una proveniente de un xml, quiza te sirva

```
                      var date = ultvisita;
                      var newdate = date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
                      console.log(newdate);//eso fue para cambiar el formato 
                     dela fecha
                    var fecha1 = moment();//eso es la fecha de hoy en segundos
                    var fecha2 = moment(newdate);//eso la fecha convertida en segundos
                    var difdias = fecha1.diff(fecha2, 'days');//esto resta 
                            ambas y nos devuelve la cantidad de dias de 
                      diferencia,luego hice unos if y me 
                      sirvio      
                     console.log(difdias)
                      </script>
```

ojala y si te ayude,"src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js">"(eso no se porque no me salia en el codigo cuando lo iba a mandar),quiza filtrando con una variable como difdias te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Como recomendación, implementa un datepicker para insertar las fechas. Si a tu usuario le permites ingresar la fecha manualmente en el campo de texto, pon una validación en tu formulario y en tu controlador.

Así cuando ingrese la fecha en formato correcto haces la conversión apropiada y la búsqueda:

```
private function convertDate($date)
{
    if ($date === null) {
        return null;
    }

    //Preferentemente es recomendable que hagas una 
    //función que no permita que la primera fecha
    //que sea mayor a la segunda 

    $dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date)); //tal vez funcione>>>   date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));  
    if ($dt) {
        return $dt->format('Y-m-d');
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Ojalá te funcione, sino a ver si vemos.